# Changing only y pos of background image via Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, background-position, jquery-hover

I want to change button's background image y position with hover function. Is there a simple way of keeping xpos or should I get position first, split it and use again with $.css() again.

I should change all 3 span's background position if somebody hover's any of them. So bt_first:hover not seems usable.

Here is my usage. I wrote #should stay same# to place that I don't want to change value of xpos:

```
$('.bt_first,.bt_sec,.bt_third').hover(function(){
        $('.bt_first,.bt_sec,.bt_third').css({'background-position':'#should stay same# -150px'})
},function(){
        $('.bt_first,.bt_sec,.bt_third').css({'background-position':'#should stay same# -110px'});
});
```

Here is my html.:

```
<div><a id="add_comment_btn"><span class="bt_first comments_t"><span>&nbsp;</span></span><span class="bt_sec">&nbsp;</span><span class="bt_third">Comments</span></a></div>
```

And css:

```
.bt_first,.bt_sec,.bt_third,.logout_t,.comments_t span {
    background: url('img/toolbar_bckrnd.png') no-repeat;
}
.bt_first {
    background-position: left -110px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 15px;
}
.bt_sec {
    background-position: -149px -110px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 2px;
}
.bt_third {
    background-position: right -110px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2117594/adding-amount-to-background-position-on-click-jquery

Comment: @thirtydot I don't think it is same. I want to change 3 different class's ypos only. xpos should stay predefined. Your post talks about something else. Am I wrong? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Kemal: I said *similar*, not *the same*. That question has code to retrieve the `background-position`, split out the two values, change one of the values, and set it back. Which is what you're trying to do.

Comment: @thirtydot oh sorry, I misunderstood. I found that post while looking for a way. Just wanted to ask if there is a simple way. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#add_comment_btn').hover(function(e) {
    var s = e.type == 'mouseenter' ? '-134px' : '-110px';        
    $(this).children().css('background-position', function(i,v) {
        return v.replace(/-?\d+px$/, s);
    });
});
```

This applies to the `#add_comment_btn` anchor. If you have multiple anchors, just use a class selector to select them all.

btw the above code is basically the same as the code that you posted in your answer. I just got rid of the redundancy.

---

btw if you don't want to add classes to the anchors, you can select them like so:

```
$('.bt_first, .bt_sec, .bt_third').parent().hover( .... the above code
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
var bg = $('#element').css('backgroundPosition').split(' ');
bg[1] = '-200px';

$('#element').css('backgroundPosition', bg.join(' '));
```

As the background-position is always stored in the order `horizontal vertical` this should work as the second array value is always the vertical value.

Though this may only work with one element. With multiple elements you may have to use a loop.

Comment: thanks. It works but it's good if I would change only one of background. I need to change all. I also have more than one button. etc.etc. it goes complex.

Answer (score 0):

I decided there is no simple solution and find a way out at the end. If somebody needs this below script works with no problem.

```
$('.bt_first,.bt_sec,.bt_third').hover(
function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('a').attr('id');
    var bg1 = $('#'+id+' > .bt_first').css('background-position').split(' ');
    var bg2 = $('#'+id+' > .bt_sec').css('background-position').split(' ');
    var bg3 = $('#'+id+' > .bt_third').css('background-position').split(' ');
    bg1[1] = '-134px';
    bg2[1] = '-134px';
    bg3[1] = '-134px';
    $('#'+id+' > .bt_first').css('background-position', bg1.join(' '));
    $('#'+id+' > .bt_sec').css('background-position', bg2.join(' '));
    $('#'+id+' > .bt_third').css('background-position', bg3.join(' '));
},
function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('a').attr('id');
    var bg1 = $('#'+id+' > .bt_first').css('background-position').split(' ');
    var bg2 = $('#'+id+' > .bt_sec').css('background-position').split(' ');
    var bg3 = $('#'+id+' > .bt_third').css('background-position').split(' ');
    bg1[1] = '-110px';
    bg2[1] = '-110px';
    bg3[1] = '-110px';
    $('#'+id+' > .bt_first').css('background-position', bg1.join(' '));
    $('#'+id+' > .bt_sec').css('background-position', bg2.join(' '));
    $('#'+id+' > .bt_third').css('background-position', bg3.join(' '));
}
);
```

You should have an "a" tag with an "id" as parent of all elements and also these elements must be first childs. Otherwise modify script.

```
<a id="add_comment_btn"><span class="bt_first comments_t"><span>&nbsp;</span></span><span class="bt_sec">&nbsp;</span><span class="bt_third">Comments</span></a>
```